# Heroku seems to be using old/cached Procfile

Tags: python, heroku

I have a Poetry + Flask project that I wanted to deploy in Heroku. I added the necessary buildpacks to work with Poetry, and I've been able to deploy my app. In an early attempt I created this wrong *Procfile*:

```
web: poetry run waitress-serve --port 5000 --call src.app:create_app
```

It obviously failed, so I fixed it to

```
web: waitress-serve --port $PORT --call src.app:create_app
```

However, even though I am deleting the app and creating it again at every attempt, the logs keep showing this:

```
2022-01-07T15:30:02.792862+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com
2022-01-07T15:30:02.792862+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com
2022-01-07T15:30:03.006025+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com
2022-01-07T15:30:03.006025+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com
2022-01-07T15:30:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com
2022-01-07T15:30:59.756696+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com
2022-01-07T15:30:59.756696+00:00 app[api]: Deploy a4c0b895 by user guillemrbaiges@gmail.com
2022-01-07T15:30:59.776519+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com
2022-01-07T15:31:07.084533+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `poetry run waitress-serve --port 5000 --call src.app:create_app`
2022-01-07T15:31:08.350024+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: poetry: command not found
2022-01-07T15:31:08.475533+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-01-07T15:31:08.548298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-07T15:31:08.642635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-01-07T15:31:15.801859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `poetry run waitress-serve --port 5000 --call src.app:create_app`
2022-01-07T15:31:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-01-07T15:31:17.220361+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: poetry: command not found
2022-01-07T15:31:17.383009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-01-07T15:31:17.476763+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Am I missing some cache? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such cache. Are you _entirely sure_ you committed your change and pushed that commit?

Comment: It is committed yes. Could the issue be related with the fact that I have added the Procfile to a project with an existing git repository created?

Comment: Fixed it, I believe you were right. Apparently destroying and creating the app over was not applying the changes on the Procfile. I had to modify the Procfile after creating an app and then applying the changes to the *heroku master* branch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was destroying and creating the Heroku app through a Makefile for debugging purposes. Apparently for the Procfile changes to apply remotely I had to modify the Procfile once the app was already created and push the changes explicitly with `git push heroku master`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What does your Makefile contain? There is probably a bug in it, or in another part of your process.